# SSH authorization key for multiple systems

Tags: ssh

Somewhere I read that to access a remote machine through SSH we need to copy `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` of the local machine to `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` of the remote machine. I did this and I can access remote machine through ssh.

I want the remote machine to be accessible from multiple servers, like: Machine A can access machine B, and there is another machine C which can also access machine B.

I copied `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` of machine A to `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` of machine B and I can access machine B.

But I also want to access machine B from machine C then what should I do? I mean, where should I copy `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` of machine C to machine B so that I can access machine B from machine C?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `authorized_keys` file on a remote host can contain more than just one public key. Just append them – make sure that each key gets a new line.

To simplify this process, there is [**`ssh-copy-id(1)`**](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ssh-copy-id).

```
ssh-copy-id user@machine-B
```

You can execute the above command on Machine C. It will copy the default public key to Machine B and append it to `authorized_keys` automatically. You can also specify another public key to be copied by using the `-i` option if you want.

---

Here's the reference [in the manual](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?ssh%201):

> The user creates his/her key pair by running `ssh-keygen(1)`. This stores the private key in […] `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` (protocol 2 RSA) in the user's home directory.  The user should then copy the public key to `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` in his/her home directory on the remote machine.
>
> The `authorized_keys` file […] has one key per line, though the lines can be very long.   After this, the user can log in without giving the password.

Comment: thanks for your reply but ssh-copy-id user@machine-B command is not working. Its giving error "ssh-copy-id: command not found".

Comment: Then you have to install it. It doesn't come with every system.

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively, you can run this command:

```
cat id_rsa.pub | ssh remote-user@remote-host "cat >>~/.ssh/authorized_keys"
```

In order to append to the authorized_keys file